# Does VertexChromaticNumber return the optimal value?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, free-wolfram-engine

The following code is meant to make a graph where each node represents a bitstring of length d and two nodes are connected if and only if the Hamming distance between their bitstrings is exactly 2. It then computes the chromatic number of the graph.

```
GetChromaticNumber[n_, d_] := 
 Module[{nodes, edges, g}, nodes = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
  edges = 
   Select[Subsets[nodes, {2}], HammingDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == d &];
  g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
  VertexChromaticNumber[g]]


GetChromaticNumber[10, 2]
```

However the code returns 17 when there is certainly a coloring with 16 colors.  Does the code not in fact do what I thought it did or is VertexChromaticNumber not computing the optimal value?

The code comes from this [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263344/116117).

---

It appears that VertexChromaticNumber does not in fact find the chromatic number. This is despite  [the online docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexChromaticNumber.html)  saying "gives the chromatic number for the vertices of the graph g."

Comment: `IGChromaticNumber` from the IGraph/M package is guaranteed to give an exact result. http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/

Comment: @Szabolcs Is that available for the free wolfram engine?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is an open source package. If you encounter issues when using it with the Free Wolfram Engine, please open an issue on GitHub and I'll look into it.

Comment: I see that your graph is huge. I am quite surprised that `VertexChromaticNumber` finishes so fast. `IGChromaticNumber` does generally very well on hard problems, but I doubt that it will finish on this huge graph. However, when it does finish, you can be sure that the result is exact.

Comment: You can also experiment with `IGKVertexColoring`. What `IGMinimumVertexColoring` and `IGChromaticNumber` essentially do is step down to smaller and smaller numbers of colours with `IGKVertexColoring` until it no longer finds a solution. For 17 colours, I get a solution in 3 seconds, but for 16 it might run for quite a long time.

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe I  have installed IGraphM but I now get :  In[28]:= GetChromaticNumber[10, 2]                                              

Out[28]= IGChromaticNumber[Graph[<1024>, <23040>]]

Comment: You did not load the package. Please read the introductory docs on the page I linked and load the package with ``Needs["IGraphM`"]``.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you. I did try to find any hint that VertexChromaticNumber might not be finding the optimal value but I didn't see anything online. For example https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexChromaticNumber.html says "gives the chromatic number for the vertices of the graph g."

Comment: The docs certainly make the impression that it should be exact. Furthermore, it is not appropriate to call it "chromatic number" if it is not exact ... I'd suggest you report this as a bug if you are sure that there is a 16-coloring (sorry, it's too late here for me to try to understand why there is one).